# The bitcoin miner lags my cpu 99% and how i will earn bitcoins

Tags: cpu

Bitcoin Miner program uses my CPU 99% can you just little make it no laggy and how do i earn bitcoins? in the internet sites and forums they dont sya anything about earning bitcoins

Comment: Are you sure they [say](http://startbitcoin.com/) [nothing](http://www.weusecoins.com/mining-guide.php) [about](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Category:Mining) [mining](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Mining) or [earning bitcoins by other means](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=99328.0)?

Answer (score 2):

Mining with a CPU is just not a sensible way to get bitcoins.

Basically, you earn bitcoins the same way you earn any other currency. You earn dollars by finding people who have dollars and offering them products, services, or items in exchange for those dollars. It's the same thing with bitcoins. Find people who have bitcoins and offer them something in exchange for them.

It's extremely difficult to mine at a profit these days. That's probably the hardest way to get bitcoins.